# Images Changing in ListView? (Parse & Picasso)

Tags: java, android, parsing, android-listview, picasso

I've been having a problem where sometimes when either a new item is added to the 
listview or the user scrolls through the listview,the image changes to something different.
Here is my adapter,how can I fix this issue?

```
public class MyBaseAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        ArrayList<ListData> myList = new ArrayList<ListData>();
        LayoutInflater inflater;
        Context context;
        String url;
        ImageView iv;
        ParseFile file;
        public MyBaseAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ListData> myList) {
                this.myList = myList;
                this.context = context;
                inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this.context);        // only context can also be used
        }
        @Override
        public int getViewTypeCount() {

            if (getCount() != 0)
                return getCount();

            return 1;
        }
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
                return myList.size();
        }

        @Override
        public ListData getItem(int position) {
                return myList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
                return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                MyViewHolder mViewHolder;
                View v = convertView;
                if(convertView == null) {
                        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_view_item, null);
                        mViewHolder = new MyViewHolder();
                        convertView.setTag(mViewHolder);
                } else {
                        mViewHolder = (MyViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
                }

                mViewHolder.tvTitle = detail(convertView, R.id.userNameBody, myList.get(position).getTitle());
                mViewHolder.tvDesc  = detail(convertView, R.id.destinyMessageBody,  myList.get(position).getDescription());
                mViewHolder.image = detail(convertView, R.id.profile_picture, myList.get(position).getImage());

Pattern tagMatcher = Pattern.compile("[#]+[A-Za-z0-9-_]+\\b");

                //Scheme for Linkify, when a word matched tagMatcher pattern,
                //that word is appended to this URL and used as content URI
                String newActivityURL = "content://com.rhynoapplications.askmethis.hashtaglookup/";

                //Attach Linkify to TextView
                Linkify.addLinks(mViewHolder.tvDesc, tagMatcher, newActivityURL);



                return convertView;
        }

        // or you can try better way
        private TextView detail(View v, int resId, String text) {
                TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(resId);
                tv.setText(text);
                TextView tv2 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.userNameBody);
                url = tv2.getText().toString();
                return tv;
        }

        private ImageView detail(View v, int resId, int icon) {

             iv = (ImageView) v.findViewById(resId);

            ParseQuery<ParseUser> userQuery = ParseUser.getQuery();
            userQuery.whereEqualTo("username", url);
            userQuery.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {
              public void done(List<ParseUser> results, ParseException e) {
                // results has the list of users with a hometown team with a winning record

                  for(ParseObject obj: results){
                      file = obj.getParseFile("profilePicture");
                  }
                  Picasso.with(context).load(file.getUrl()).resize(200,200).placeholder(R.drawable.destiny_image).into(iv);
              }
            });


            return iv;
        }


        public class MyViewHolder {
                public TextView tvTitle, tvDesc;
                public ImageView image;

        }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing your `getView` method as below

```
@Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                MyViewHolder mViewHolder;
                View v = convertView;
                if(convertView == null) {
                        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_view_item, null);
                        mViewHolder = new MyViewHolder();

                        mViewHolder.tvTitle = detail(convertView, R.id.userNameBody, myList.get(position).getTitle());
                        mViewHolder.tvDesc  = detail(convertView, R.id.destinyMessageBody,  myList.get(position).getDescription());
                        mViewHolder.image = detail(convertView, R.id.profile_picture, myList.get(position).getImage());
                        convertView.setTag(mViewHolder);

                } else {
                        mViewHolder = (MyViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
                }

                .. your other code goes here 
        }
```

Comment: It's working,but now it's duplicating items after a certain amount of items.

Comment: what do you mean by duplicating ? Can you explain what is actually happening ?

Comment: I have a button in which add items to the listview,I'll add let's say 3 items,when i press the button again it'll begin to loop those 3,adding those 3 items from the top to the listview over and over again instead of adding what I told it to add.

Comment: You might be going wrong while adding those items to ListView,  I guess.

Comment: @User22791 Great Yar...!!